# Is it possible for mysqli_insert_id to return an incorrect id in high traffic applications?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, high-traffic

In a high traffic application, is it possible for `mysqli_insert_id()` to return the wrong id, or to confuse the id between two `INSERT` queries performed nearly simultaneously?

Comment: FYI this is called a [*Race Condition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. `mysqli_insert_id` returns the most the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value from the most recent `INSERT` query on the current connection. It will never get confused with another connection, for example.

Comment: last insert id depends on the connection. this solved my doubt.

Answer (score 4):

No. How can I be so sure? Because it would have been reported and fixed a *long* time ago.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from a previous answer to this exact same question:

Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/getting-unique-id.html for more information, it says this:

> "For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and
>   not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns
>   simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client
>   will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client
>   executed."

So you should be fine doing what you want and you shouldn't get strange results.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is posible! If you have multiple tables to insert with same connection and your last insert was incorrect (like I trying insert unescaped quotes in text).

I think it returns last **successful** insert id which can by from different table. I just spent hour to find this. Peace

Comment: While true this is not what the question asked about. You are describing a situation when you ignore reported errors and then get confused about the ID. That one is on you for silencing error reporting. `mysqli_insert_id()` will always return the correct ID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you insert a negative number into a signed int autoincrement column mysqli_insert_id() will return 18446744073709551615. If the column is signed bigint mysqli_insert_id() will return 0 (in both cases the record is correctly inserted) https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69228

Comment: I'm using a negative row id on an unsigned auto-increment column (for testing purposes) and sure enough, I get the world's most unhelpful number above returned as the insert id.