# Return newly inserted index value

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `Production` and `Production_Detail`. `Production_Detail` holds details of some order and has a foreign key to `Production`.  When I insert a row into `Production`, auto-incrementing column sets the key for that row.  I need that key so that it can be linked with the new `Production_Detail` rows that will be inserted after inserting the master row in `Production`.

Using php, I insert the data:

```
insert into Production Values ('','$producer_id','$order_date','$company_id','$emp_id');
```

I need to find that `''` part so that it can be used for later quires.

Comment: Depends on what function or method you use to perform the insert

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266604/select-last-insert-id Duplicated many times.

Comment: i am using ajax to call this, and i want that id so that i can using that id with other insertion quires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In depends what mysql/query extension you're using, but PHP has a [`mysql_insert_id`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function to return the auto increment value for the most recently inserted row.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PDO you can use the function

```
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: but what if there are multiple users using that script? won't it result in a conflict?

Comment: No. I don't know the exact way to explain that, but it will give you the id of the query just above, because it's the same "connection" to the data base. Maybe somebody else can explain precisely.

Comment: Thanks! I read the description and it says that it opens a connection with the `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: Also a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315200/is-it-possible-for-mysqli-insert-id-to-return-an-incorrect-id-in-high-traffic-ap

Comment: If you use `mysql_connect()`, you need to use mysql_insert_id(), like somebody else said. the `lastInsertId()` works if you use the PDO extension

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are using the database you may have to pass the database variable.

mysql

```
$last_id = mysql_insert_id($db);
```

mysqli

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
```