# expected ID returned for mysqli_insert_id() is different than actual

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I can't figure out why the id returned with mysqli_insert_id() is different than my expected id. Here is my code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO payments_table (payment_type, payment_number, payment_cost, insertion_date) VALUES ( '$paymentType', '$paymentNumber', '$totalCost', NOW())";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$currentPayerID = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

//DEBUG
echo 'current payerID is: ' . $currentPayerID;
```

Since there are currently 2 rows, I expect it to echo "current payerID is 3" after the next execution. However, after executing this code, it echoes the following:
"current payerID is 21"

A couple notes:

1. This 'payments_table' table has a column named "payer_id" that is a
   primary key and has the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute.
2. I've "truncated" this table(I believe this is the same as emptying it out).

I searched throughout stackoverflow, but some of the answer don't [believe that what I'm finding is possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315200/is-it-possible-for-mysqli-insert-id-to-return-an-incorrect-id-in-high-traffic-ap) I appreciate any generous help!

Comment: check in your table what is the last id generated.

Comment: after 21 , in the next insert what it is returning? and please see your db table. what is storing in you DB? please tell.

Comment: Hi @YogeshSuthar, thanks for answering. The last ID generated is "3".

Comment: Why are you expecting `3`? Please update your question to show the output of `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'payments_table';`

Comment: Hi @ripa. My table is storing IDs in regular ascending order. The last id stored is "3". The value returned by mysqli_insert_id($dbc) is also ascending, and is currently "21".

Comment: Are there any other `INSERT` or `UPDATE` queries being executed by this script? `mysqli_insert_id` returns the *last* `AUTO_INCREMENT` value - if you're inserting or updating another table after `payments_table` but before calling `mysqli_insert_id` you may be getting an unexpected value.

Comment: @ChrisG ok. insert new record. and say your db table stored id and printing id. then can say what is actually wrong. thanks.

Comment: @leepowers Yup that was part of the issue. Thank you so much, I kept overlooking that until your suggestion. I really appreciate it. How can I upvote your comment?!

Comment: @ripa that also helped too. How can I upvote your comments?

Comment: @ChrisG there is an uparrow in the left. click on that. will upvote me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_insert_id` returns the *last* `AUTO_INCREMENT` value - if you're inserting to another table after `payments_table` but *before* calling `mysqli_insert_id` you may be getting an unexpected value.

Also an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column does not correspond with the number of rows in the database table, but the total number of rows over the lifetime of the table. More precisely, MySQL maintains a counter variable that is incremented each time a new row is created.

The following query will show the next expected `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for a table:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table_name';
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are expecting is wrong.

Having a field using auto increment allows you to insert data and generate a unique primary key by incrementing it by one with every insert.

What this means for you is that the returned to you is a uniquely created UD and not the number of inserted rows in your table.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli_insert_id` function returns the `ID` generated by a query on a table with a column having the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute. If the last query was not an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute, this function will return zero.

It may be you have truncate and last id was 20 then it giving you 21. Now try once.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, user2001117. I believe I understand your tip. However, I believe my last query is clearly an INSERT statement. And as I mentioned above, the function is returning "21" instead of an expected "3".