# Is it safe to get ID through lastInsertId()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've a database with hundreds of records which inserted in each seconds, I have the below insert query and I want to know the insert id of this query:

```
   $currQuery = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO some_table (...... )");
   $currQuery->execute("....");
   $queryInsertId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

I just want to know that is it safe to use `lastInsertId()` while I having hundreds of new records in every seconds? any ideas?

Comment: So, are you worried that if you have too many users hitting this page, that `lastInsertId` will return the wrong value?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yup, exactly...

Comment: [is it possible for mysqli_insert_id to return an incorrect id in high-traffic app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315200/is-it-possible-for-mysqli-insert-id-to-return-an-incorrect-id-in-high-traffic-ap/9315402#9315402)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe. It returns the last insert id for the connection.